# How to send binary data in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, unicode, binary

I want to send binary data from a html page to my server via JavaScript, but the server received not the same bytes. The received bytes seems to be converted to a unicode string, see the following example:

```
xhr.open('POST', '/check', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
xhr.send('\x41\xFE\x80');
```

The server should receive 'Aþ€' but it get `A├¥┬Ç`.

I tested a lot of things like:

```
//xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1');
//xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1');
//xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8');
//xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
//xhr.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
```

On server side I run *plackup* (*http://localhost:5000/index.html*), and `$env->{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}` is 5, so the server really seems to get the 5 bytes `A├¥┬Ç`.

Any hint how to receive the original binary data would be great.

Comment: [MDN: Sending and Receiving Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), especially [Sending typed arrays as binary data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_typed_arrays_as_binary_data)

Comment: Yes, I know this sample and used it. IMHO my Javascript is correct, maybe the script on the server cause this error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IMHO my Javascript is correct

It is not. As I hinted in a comment, use `Uint8Array`, not strings, for binary data:

```
xhr.send(new Uint8Array([0x41, 0xFE, 0x80]));
```

If you already have a string... this should work:

```
xhr.send(new Uint8Array(Array.from('\x41\xFE\x80').map(x => x.charCodeAt(0)))
```

The explanation: The [spec for `send`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method) says:

> If `body` is a `Document`, then set request body to `body`, serialized, converted to Unicode, and UTF-8 encoded.
>
> Otherwise, set request body and `extractedContentType` to the result of extracting `body`.

`String` is not a `Document`, therefore the first option does not apply. The definition of "extracting" is found in the [`fetch` spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract):

> USVString:
>
> Set `action` to an action that runs UTF-8 encode on `object`.
>
> Set `Content-Type` to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`.
>
> Set `source` to `object`.

And you can see how UTF-8 encoding of your string looks like:

```
new TextEncoder().encode('\x41\xFE\x80')
// => Uint8Array(5) [65, 195, 190, 194, 128]
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! But why does the solution from Adelin doesn't work?

Comment: I commented on it. Blob is just an abstraction over arbitrary content, thus he was not doing anything substantially different than you: in the end, it was still a string that was transmitted. Don't use strings for binary data.

Comment: But I found on [sendAsBinary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/sendAsBinary): The send() method now supports binary data and should now be used instead. So *send()* should also work!?

Comment: @Codr: From your link: "Warning: This method is obsolete and should not be used. You should instead simply use the `send()` method, which now supports binary data in various forms." And `send()` does work - I just demonstrated it in my answer.

Comment: `Uint8Array` (that I used) is a kind of `ArrayBufferView`. And again, `Blob` is just a container, and will behave like whatever datasource you initialise it with: if you initialise it with a 5-byte string, it will send 5 bytes just like the string. Check this: `var blob = new Blob(['\x41\xFE\x80'], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}); var reader = new FileReader(); reader.addEventListener("loadend", () => console.log(reader.result)); reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)`.